# Wie baut man eine Frage mit mehreren Verben?

Tags: sentence-structure

Wie kann man am besten eine Frage bauen, die mehrere Verben hat.  Zum Beispiel:

> Do you say such things and call yourself his friend?

Da Deutsch Inversion verwendet, um eine Frage zu bauen, muss sich »du« wiederholen, wie folgt?

> Sagst du solche Dinge, und nennst du dich seinen Freund?

Oder gibt es eine bessere Lösung?

Comment: _Sagst du solche Dinge und nennst dich seinen Freund?_ scheint mir genauso korrekt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Antwort ist sehr einfach:

> Du sagst solche Dinge and nennst dich „sein Freund”?

Im Deutschen **können** Fragesätze invertiert werden, sie müssen es aber nicht. Es reicht, am Ende eines Aussagesatzes die Stimme zu heben, statt wie gewohnt zu senken. Das wird als Frage verstanden.

Comment: Vielleicht erwähnenswert: Dieser Satz ist zwar semantisch eine Frage (also eine Äußerung, die eine Antwort herausfordert), grammatisch aber kein Fragesatz (Verb an Position 1), sondern ein Aussagesatz (Verb an Position 2). Das Fragezeichen am Ende macht in der Grammatik aus diesem Satz noch keinen Fragesatz. Das Fragezeichen zeigt aber eine andere Sprachmelodie an (heben der Stimme in der letzen Silbe anstatt sie zu senken), und erst an dieser anderen Melodie erkennt man die (semantische) Frage (aber das hast du ja ohnehin völlig korrekt beschrieben).